# Getting list of questions that has not been shown or answered

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables :

Question table where contains :

[image]

And then I have another table that is called

UserAnswerQuestion that contains :

[image]

That has reference to the question via `question_id`

The thing is that every time user answers a question I create a row in db saying :

question_id user_id has answered it and then I check if the answer is correct or not, if it's correct I put passed as a True, otherwise I put passed as a false.

Ok, from now is all ok, the thing that I can not get is I'm creating a method that returns to me the nextQuestion not answered, but I'm not able to do this method correctly.

What I'd like is to have a query that first return all questions that user have not answered yet, and then another query that returns just a question that user has not answered yet.

Note: This shown attribute was added because I want first to iterate over other questions instead of showing the ones that user has failed recently.

Is the question clear?

### What I've tried?

I've tried to get the questions `List<UserAnswerQuestion> findAllByUserEmailAndPassedFalseAndShownFalse(String email);` but it doesn't work because with this table I can know every answer in every try that user does, so for example if I have a question that have 4 answers and 1 correct, this table can contain 4 row with the same question_question_id because the user perhaps has failed 3 times and then at the fourth it answers correctly.

### Edit

I have already the questions that user can answer with this method :

```
public List<Question> getAllQuestionsThatUserCanAnswer(String email, Long topic){
        List<Question> mList = this.questionRepository.findAllByTopicParentId(topic);
        if(mList==null) return null;
        List<UserAnswerQuestion> userAnswerQuestionList = this.userAnswerQuestionRepository.findAllByUserEmail(email);

        for (UserAnswerQuestion userAnswerQuestion : userAnswerQuestionList) {
            if(mList.contains(userAnswerQuestion.getQuestion())){
                if(userAnswerQuestion.getPassed()){
                    mList.remove(userAnswerQuestion.getQuestion());
                }
            }
        }
        return mList;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to do the getNext of this method but I do not know how to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on SQL query that solve your problem

```
select * from Question q
left join Answer a on q.id = a.question_id
where a.id is null OR (a.passed != 'true' AND a.user_id = 1)
order by a.passed
```

Check scratch [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88b47b/12)